# easy way to typedef primitive type in entire program?

Tags: c#

I'm using `long` instead of `decimal` for performance reasons.

I want to distinguish `long` which means `long` from `long` which means `decimal`. So I want to declare something like `using myDecimal = System.Int64;`. But such declaration is visible only in the file it declared. I need something that can be used in entire program.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/141385/typedef-in-C) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/019a258e-8d50-4a9f-b0ef-8311208ebb6a/typedefequivalent-in-c?forum=csharplanguage) it's suggested to create "wrapper" class but it looks so awkward! I think I better copy-paste `using myDecimal = System.Int64;` to every file i'm using.

Am I correct that i do not have anything better than these two options?

Why I don't want to just use `long`? Because of readability! Just compare

```
public class FutTradeEntry
{
    public long orderId;
    public int status;
    public int amount;
    public int amount_rest;
    public sbyte action;
    public myDecimal price;
    public myDecimal deal_price;
    public int ext_id;
}
```

and

```
public class FutTradeEntry
{
    public long orderId;
    public int status;
    public int amount;
    public int amount_rest;
    public sbyte action;
    public long price;
    public long deal_price;
    public int ext_id;
}
```

It's very confusing to have the same type `long` to store completely different things. Every time I see `long` variable I should think "What is it, long or decimal?"

Comment: I'm curious about the intention here; decimal and long behave very differently, so it's unclear where you'd ever switch between them as a compilation option.

Comment: @DanBryant (I would assume what the OP is doing is) Essentially if you want to represent a non-integer value D using long L, you would write it as `L = D * 10 ^ X` where X is some fixed value.  Essentially you know that all of the longs are some power of ten larger than the number they actually represent.  This is, more or less, what `Decimal` does internally, except that with `Decimal` X isn't fixed; some of the bits of the value indicate what it is.  For example, if the OP is representing currency, rather than using `Decimal` he can essentially use a long to represent the number of cents.

Comment: A `long` is a `long`.  `long` == `System.Int64`  When does `long` mean `decimal` in your program?

Comment: Using the term `decimal` leads to a lot of confusion from those reading the question, since `decimal` is an existing C# type.  I believe the intent is thus: You have (for example), two functions, `GetPerson(long id)` and `GetOrder(long id)`.  Even though the underlying type is a long, you wish to change the signatures to `GetPerson(PersonID id)` and `GetOrder(OrderID id)`, such that the compiler will protect you against accidentally calling `GetOrder` with a personID.

Comment: Servy is correct, this is financical application (HFT trading) so I just store something like "number of cents"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I correct that i do not have anything better than these two options?

No, there is a third option: say `long` when the thing is a `long`, end of story. That's what I'd do.

Comment: Technically speaking you are right. From a programming safety point of view, you are wrong. There's a ton of good reasons to have strongly-typed primitive type options. The only tiny, little, unimportant detail is the C-like family of languagues doesn't support this idea well :-)

Comment: @OndrejTucny: I totally agree with you. If the redefined `long` had semantics other than that of a number then I would recommend creating a wrapper type that clearly described those semantics.

Comment: Well, yes, I'm *assuming* there's some special semantincs, by default.

Comment: ok i will have `long numberOfItemsToSell = 100` and `long priceOfOneItem = 9999`. When first long means `100 items` second long means `99.99$`. Don't you find that these two longs are very different? Isn't it better to have `myDecimal` for second long so I can easily understand what type of long is used?

Comment: @javapowered I don't understand the objection. 9999 pennies per item times 100 items is 999900 pennies. What's the problem?

Comment: the problem is that long values need to be processed differently. When I receive 99.99 (for example from network) i should change it to 9999. Then I work everywhere with "9999" but before displaying to user I should change it back to "99.99". I should not do this tricks with regular long values so i need to distinguish `long-decimal` from `long`

Comment: @javapowered: Using `system.decimal` everywhere makes this problem go away.  Using anything else should be the exception rather than the rule...though as I understand it HFT's performance requirements can be brutal enough to force such exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

There's no other option. Just the alias via `using` or a `struct` wrapper. Personally I'd choose a `struct` wrapper, because it provides better type safety and you can define overloaded operators as needed. It's more work, but better than copy&pasting a single line of code across the whole code base, which would be a lot more error-prone and less maintainable.

Note that wrapping it with a `class` would make it a *reference* type, while a `struct` is a *value* type (same as `long` and other primitive types).

Comment: I'm afraid `struct` wrapper kills the main point of using long instead of decimal - performance. `struct` wrapper will add overhead, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

It's still not clear to me what the goal here is, but here's one (slightly smelly) way to create a 'new name' for at least the integer subset of primitive types:

```
public enum MyMeaningfulLong : long
{
}
```

It's a bit stronger than a typedef, but it has similar effects.  The bigger issue here, though, is that it's somewhat against the spirit of 'enum', which is to represent one of a set of known constant values.  A wrapper class (possibly with implicit conversions) is a cleaner approach.